# Python String Accumulator for Lists

Tags: python, string, accumulator

I am still trying to learn pythons basics and am having trouble.
I have an assignment for a class and needed a little guidance.

I'm trying to take integer values from input from a user and then add them to a
string list for as many items the user would like.

I can easily add string values inputted by the user into a list, but it comes out like so:

```
['Test1','Test2','Test3']
```

I would like to have it come out as:

```
{Test1, Test2, Test3}
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
# Tests before creating function
# definition. 
salesFigures = [] 
maxLengthList = 3
while len(salesFigures) < maxLengthList:
    item = input("Enter your sales figure to be added: ")
    salesFigures.append(item)
print("These are your sales figures:")
print(salesFigures)
```

Comment: So, like, `'{' + ', '.join(salesFigures) + '}'`?

Comment: This worked well and easy, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use **`join()`** + **string formatting**:

```
some_list = ['Test1','Test2','Test3']
desired_results = "{{{}}}".format(', '.join(some_list))
print desired_results
```

**Output:**

```
{Test1, Test2, Test3}
```

Comment: join() + string formatting this method worked as well with the same results. Much appreciated!

Comment: @justachillGamer good to know that my answer helped! It's my pleasure.